# MongoDB Document: is there a way to get subdocument with the dot?

Tags: java, mongodb, document, mongo-java-driver

I'm working with mongodb and it's latest java driver, and I want a convenient way to get a subdocument

```
    Document d = Document.parse("{ parent : { child : 'foo'} }"); // d could be the result of a findOne query

    // I can't do this -- would be very convenient
    LOG.debug("Broken child value : " + d.getString("parent.child")); // shows null

    // I must do this -- very inconvenient
    LOG.debug("Child value : " + ((Document) d.get("parent")).getString("child")); // shows foo
```

To get subdocument, I must use the inconvenient `((Document) d.get("parent")).getString("child")`.
Is there any way to get the subdocument with the dot operator ?

Comment: This is the problem with using Document class. You need to create a class matching with your json structure in mongo. Then things will be much easier

Comment: You can also use JSON.parse. But that wouldn't be any better, in that case you will have to typecast it to BasicDbObject